# Stop loading unnecessary symbols

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nopcommerce

I'm working with nopCommerce and it works well. The only problem is that it takes a lot of time for web app to start.  After I hit F5 it takes around 45 seconds before it gets to Application_Start method. (If I hit 'Start Without Debugging' it takes like 7 seconds). So I believe the problem is because symbols being loaded and I can't disable them.  I tried to set 'Only specified modules' (Debug-> Options-> Debugging -> Symbols) but anyway it keeps trying to load dozens of unnecessary symbols files:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDoma

Is it possible just to load symbols only for some of dlls?

Comment: Hi @Stanislav! Which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Hi @stratever! It is 2015

Comment: Hi. According to your log those symbols are not being loaded. `...Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized...`

Comment: I think that you can disable symbol loading attempt via Debug > Windows > Modules.